# Using AVG in Spark with window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following SQL Query:

```sql
Select st.Value,
       st.Id,
       ntile(2) OVER (PARTITION BY St.Id, St.VarId ORDER By St.Sls),
       AVG(St.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY St.Id, St.VarId ORDER By St.Sls, St.Date)
FROM table tb
INNER JOIN staging st on St.Id = tb.Id
```

I've tried to adapt this to Spark/PySpark using window function, my code is below:

```py
windowSpec_1 = Window.partitionBy("staging.Id", "staging.VarId").orderBy("staging.Sls")
windowSpec_2 = Window.partitionBy("staging.Id", "staging.VarId").orderBy("staging.Sls", "staging.Date")

df= table.join(
    staging,
    on=f.col("staging.Id") == f.col("table.Id"),
    how='inner'
).select(
    f.col("staging.Value"),
    f.ntile(2).over(windowSpec_1),
    f.avg("staging.Value").over(windowSpec_2)
)
```

Although I'm getting the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from Value#42928: need struct type but got decimal(16,6)
```

How Can I solve this problem? Is it necessary to group data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to assign alias to `staging`?:

```
df= table.join(
    staging.alias("staging"),
    on=f.col("staging.Id") == f.col("table.Id"),
    how='inner'
).select(
    f.col("staging.Value"),
    f.ntile(2).over(windowSpec_1),
    f.avg("staging.Value").over(windowSpec_2)
)
```